# Using regular expressions to compare numbers

Tags: regex

So this is an obvious case of "you're doing it wrong".  I don't actually intend on doing this, but a conversation at work spurred this question:

> Can you generate a regular expression to determine if an integer is less than an arbitrary value.

For some values this is easy.  For integers less than 1000, \d{1,3} should do the trick.  For integers < 500, it's a bit trickier, but not that bad, as you can use [0-4]{0,1}\d{1,2}.

Once you get to arbitrary values it gets a lot tricker.  For example, all numbers less than 255 would be something like \d{1,2} | [0-1]\d{2}|[2][0-4]\d | [2][5][0-4].

Is there a single regular expression that works here?  Or do you have to programatically generate the regex?

(And again, let me point out that I have no intention of actually doing this.  Obviously using "foo < bar" in your favorite programming language is far more efficient and easy to read.)

Comment: You could combine the three expressions you have to get a single one if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 5):

This is quite easy.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Regexp::Assemble;

for my $n (@ARGV)  {
    my $asm = new Regexp::Assemble;
    for (1 .. $n) { $asm->add($_) }
    for ($asm->re){
        s/\)$/\$/;
        s/^[^:]*:/^/;
        print "$n => /$_/\n";
    }
}
```

Now run it to find the pattern that matches integers between 1 and that number:

```
$ perl /tmp/ra 5 15 153 401 1144
5 => /^[12345]$/
15 => /^(?:[23456789]|1[012345]?)$/
153 => /^(?:1(?:[6789]|5[0123]?|0\d?|1\d?|2\d?|3\d?|4\d?)?|2\d?|3\d?|4\d?|5\d?|6\d?|7\d?|8\d?|9\d?)$/
401 => /^(?:1(?:0\d?|1\d?|2\d?|3\d?|4\d?|5\d?|6\d?|7\d?|8\d?|9\d?)?|2(?:0\d?|1\d?|2\d?|3\d?|4\d?|5\d?|6\d?|7\d?|8\d?|9\d?)?|3(?:0\d?|1\d?|2\d?|3\d?|4\d?|5\d?|6\d?|7\d?|8\d?|9\d?)?|4(?:[123456789]|0[01]?)?|5\d?|6\d?|7\d?|8\d?|9\d?)$/
1144 => /^(?:1(?:0(?:0\d?|1\d?|2\d?|3\d?|4\d?|5\d?|6\d?|7\d?|8\d?|9\d?)?|1(?:[56789]|4[01234]?|0\d?|1\d?|2\d?|3\d?)?|2\d?|3\d?|4\d?|5\d?|6\d?|7\d?|8\d?|9\d?)?|2(?:0\d?|1\d?|2\d?|3\d?|4\d?|5\d?|6\d?|7\d?|8\d?|9\d?)?|3(?:0\d?|1\d?|2\d?|3\d?|4\d?|5\d?|6\d?|7\d?|8\d?|9\d?)?|4(?:0\d?|1\d?|2\d?|3\d?|4\d?|5\d?|6\d?|7\d?|8\d?|9\d?)?|5(?:0\d?|1\d?|2\d?|3\d?|4\d?|5\d?|6\d?|7\d?|8\d?|9\d?)?|6(?:0\d?|1\d?|2\d?|3\d?|4\d?|5\d?|6\d?|7\d?|8\d?|9\d?)?|7(?:0\d?|1\d?|2\d?|3\d?|4\d?|5\d?|6\d?|7\d?|8\d?|9\d?)?|8(?:0\d?|1\d?|2\d?|3\d?|4\d?|5\d?|6\d?|7\d?|8\d?|9\d?)?|9(?:0\d?|1\d?|2\d?|3\d?|4\d?|5\d?|6\d?|7\d?|8\d?|9\d?)?)$/
```

Answer (score 3):

You're going to need to generate the expression for each bounding number.  Let's say there were a regular expression that would do the job.  Then that regular expression would have to be able to take as input some sequence of characters.  However, we know that regular expressions and finite state automata are equivalent, so this is the same as saying we can construct an FSM since the possible number is unbounded, that would require an unbounded number of states, which contradicts the definition of FSA.

Comment: Huh? Are you saying it can't be done, or is this a really funny way of saying yes? Are you alluding to negative numbers, even though the OP is clearly implying non-negative number space?

Comment: Can't be done.  You can't write a regexp that will, in general, tell you if an arbitrary number is greater than an arbitrary bound, because they're not finite.

Comment: If OP means just a particular number, he can do it trivially -- enumuerate all the values below his bound.  Then if he's feeling ambitious, minimize the corresponding FSM and use the minimal regex.

Comment: @tripleee: 'of arbitrary length, yet finite' is a contradiction by semantics alone, no knowledge of automatons required. Reminds me of verizon's data plan.