# Can we validate Min and Max Value for a floating Number using RegExp?

Tags: regex, max, min

Hi I know that we can validate Min and Max Length of a number using Regex.
But can we validate **Min and Max Value** for a floating point number using the same?

- Min Value : 0.00
- Max Value :100,000,000.00

Could anyone please just apply Min and Max Value to following Regex:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?!.*?\.[^.\n]*,)\d*(,\d*,?)*(\.\d*)?$
```

Above Regex matches a floating number with optional decimal point and commas.

Comment: regex?? please, don't...

Comment: @Karoly, Is it not possible?

Comment: I guess it's doable. But I don't care. It's a horrible idea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using regular expressions to compare numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434844/using-regular-expressions-to-compare-numbers)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Regex is for strings. You try to compare floats. It's just not the right tool. It's worse than eating your soup with a fork. It's like writing on paper with a knife or cutting your hair with a teaspoon.

Look here for a solution with positive integers without thousands separator :
[Using regular expressions to compare numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434844/using-regular-expressions-to-compare-numbers)

I leave the task to you to extend that solution to using floats, thousands separator and negative numbers.

Comment: Thanks @Lorenz. Now I get it that it will be tough and not a good practise to compare numbers using Regex. This idea came to me as I wanted to lessen my Lines of Code. Anyways Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this should help you. This regex will match `0.00` to `100,000,000.00` upto 2 decimal places.

```
^(:?(?=[1])(10{0,8})|(?=[^0])(\d{1,8})|0)\.[0-9]{1,2}$
```

But keep in mind that its always best to compare numbers numerically that using regex.

[Here is the link](http://regex101.com/r/rR4xG2/3) to verify it.

Comment: What is the purpose of `(:? … )` here? Did you mean non-capturing group `(?: … )`?