# Regex values 0,01 and 9.999.999.999.999,99

Tags: regex

I need a regex that allows values between 0,01 and 9.999.999.999.999,99. Any suggestions?

I am using the following regex:

```
"(?:(?:[0-9]\\d{0,2})(?:\\.\\d{3})*(?:,\\d{2})|0,(?:[0-9]\\d|0[0-9]))"
```

But it allows 0,00

Thank you for your help

Comment: Maybe regex alone is not the best way to solve this problem. What about a first pass with a regex that validates only the character pattern, followed by some non-regex logic that validates the range requirements?

Comment: what do `,` and `.` mean in your expression? i feel like you are using them in the reversed way. if it's number, parse it to number. it's not the job for regex.

Comment: I'll check this suggestion. Thank you Asaph

Comment: HuStmpHrr, The idea is to validate the range of amounts to two decimal places except 0,00

Comment: is matching something like `01,00` acceptable?

Comment: A good reason for the concerns others have raised here might be the cultural implications of your validation. In the UK numbers would be formatted with commas and dots transposed. E.g  999,999.99

Comment: If `0,01` is meant to be representing 1/100 (i.e. one hundredth), then you should be writing `0.01`. The same for the `9.999.999.999.999,99` being `9.99x10^13`, then swap your commas (`,`) with full stops, or more commonly known as a decimal point (`.`)

Comment: @jbutler483: this is very locale centric. not everyone uses `.` as decimal separator.

Comment: @njzk2 I/We learn something new every day I just looked up [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark)

Comment: @jbutler483 yep. this has been the source of major headaches...

Comment: compare floats with regexps is nosense. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958458/can-we-validate-min-and-max-value-for-a-floating-number-using-regexp/26959774#26959774

Answer (score 1):

If all you're wanting to do is validate then this regex should work for you.

```
(?:(?!(?:0{1,3}\.){0,}0{1,3},00)(?:\d{1,3}\.){0,}\d?\d?(?:(0)|\d),\d(?(1)[1-9]|\d))
```

[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xB7qE5/4)

I've updated it so that if the value is `0,00` it will not match, but it'll match `10.000,00` or `1,00`

The regex will match:

```
10.000,00
1,00
0,01 
10,00
9.999.999.999.999,99
```

The regex will not match:

```
0,00
0.000,00
```

Comment: This doesn't match 1,00

Comment: i am pretty sure 1,00 is supposed to be valid

Comment: [1-9] is wrong here, zero is valid if the total count is != 0

Comment: @SamGreenhalgh: I've updated the regex to fix that issue. Thanks for pointing it out. I obviously wasn't paying attention.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure regex would be the most appropriate tool for this job here, however I think this is what you are looking for.

```
(?=[\d\.]*[1-9][\d\.]*,\d{2}|[\d\.]*,[\d\.]*[1-9][\d\.]*)(\d{1,3}\.)*\d{0,3},\d{2}
```

the positive lookahead enforces the non-zero value

```
(?=[\d\.]*[1-9][\d\.]*,\d{2}|[\d\.]*,[\d\.]*[1-9][\d\.]*)
```

and the rest just matches the pattern

```
(\d{1,3}\.)*\d{0,3},\d{2}
```

http://regexr.com/39ujm

Comment: Doesn't match `10,00`

Comment: Sam, thanks for the link is of good help to perform the tests

Answer (score 1):

0,01 - 0,99 is a particular case. So is 9.999.999.999.999,99. I would do:

```
(0,((\d[1-9])|([1-9]\d)))|((([1-9]\d{0,2}(\.\d{3}){0,3})|([1-9](\.\d{3}){4})),\d{2})
```

### Edit

As pointed out by Biffen, 0,x0 is also a special case

Comment: Doesn't match `0,10`, `0,20`, etc.

Comment: right. so 0,-- is a special case, and 0,01 is a special case in the special case.