# Regex between 1.00 and 99.00

Tags: regex

I need to find a regular expression that will only allow input between 1.00 and 99.00 So anything below 1.00 and greater than 99.00 is not acceptable.

Comment: Duplicate:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958458/can-we-validate-min-and-max-value-for-a-floating-number-using-regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958458/can-we-validate-min-and-max-value-for-a-floating-number-using-regexp)

Comment: `regex` is not the appropriate tool for the job. You can use `regex` to check if the string looks like a number then extract the numeric value from it and compare that value against the limits of the acceptable range.

Comment: So anything below 1.00 and greater than 90.00 is not acceptable. Don't you mean 99.00 in that second sentence, or 90.00 in that first sentence?

Comment: How on earth this question received 2 upvotes?!

Comment: Don't. Just don't. What's the problem with `double n; if (double.TryParse("99.0", out n) && n >= 1.0 && n <= 99.0) Console.WriteLine("Valid.");` No one will be able to understand and maintain that Regex. What will you do when the valid range has to be changed? Come back to StackOverflow and ask the same question again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to accept integers too:

```
^(?(?=99)99(\.0+)?|([1-9]\d?(\.\d+)?))$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/pXlYFF/1)

Comment: Nearly 99.01 failed though

Comment: 99.01 should have failed

Comment: Yes range should be 1.00 to 99.00

Comment: This is not the answer. This does not match any value in the 90's except for 99.00. It does't match any value between 90.00 - 98.99

Comment: Hi. I also need it to accept the first part of the number and the decimal point. Eg. 10.

Answer (score 0):

Try this- This will match 1 to 90

```
 ^[1-9][0-9]?$|^90$
```

[Working Fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/eWihjD/1/)

Comment: What about 1.23 ?

Answer (score 0):

Regex is bad for this kind of validation because there are too many if this then that rules involved. This pattern will work, though.

`^(?:[1-9]\.\d{2}|[1-8]\d\.\d{2}|9[0-8]\.\d{2}|99.00)$`

It has been tested for all 10,000 possible values between 0.00 and 99.99

Comment: Doesn't work between 99.01 and 99.99 because you're setting 99.00 literally. Pretty close though! Thanks.

Comment: (^\d{1}\.|[1-9]\d\.)(\d{2})$

Comment: @jDub9 The question says valid range is only up to 99.00, and that is why I provided an answer that only matches up to 99.00. If you have different validation rules than what the question is asking for, that's fine, but you can't tell me that I answered this question incorrectly just because you have a different question.