# Regex Number Below 90

Tags: regex

I need to validate that percent complete is < 90.00, so basically 89.99 and below.

I was able to get regex to work with whole numbers:

`^(?:[0-9]|(?:[1-8][0-9]))$`

However, I need to be able to match one the decimal too and find it within the below string.

`Endpointgroup Name::ALL::Endpointgroup Description::::SQLRun TS::2017-06-19 14:15:02::ORIGINAL_NODE=CE01::ORIGINAL_NODE=CE01::Total EP::940256::Completed EP::869655::Job Status::W::Percent Complete::92.49`

Comment: Numeric comparison should not be done using regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will capture strings where the number following the `Complete::` is less or equal 89.99. You can get the number from the first capturing group.

```
Complete::([0-8]?[0-9]\.[0-9][0-9])
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite ugly to do with regex. See the posts

> [Validate max-min with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958458/can-we-validate-min-and-max-value-for-a-floating-number-using-regexp) and [Use regex to compare numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434844/using-regular-expressions-to-compare-numbers)